# matchMedia does not simulate CSS media queries completely referring to device orientation

Tags: javascript, css, screen-orientation, matchmedia

I'm kind of confused with JavaScript's matchMedia. I created a JavaScript version of this CSS media queries code and I was expecting that it will display like the CSS version of media queries of a orientation of portrait and landscape this work perfectly

on mobile devices but on a computer when I resize the browser the JavaScript version first shows the landscape orientation first and the more I resize it then it starts to show the portrait orientation code but the CSS version does

not do that.The CSS version literally detects a change of device orientation So why am I getting this effect with the JavaScript version? and how can I make it more similar to the CSS version? or should I use another method to do this more effectively?

The CSS version

```css
#output{
color: white;
}

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 320px) 
and (max-width : 736px){
#output{
 background-color: red;
}
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : landscape){
#output{
 background-color: blue;
}
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<style>

</style>

<p id='output'>XXX</p>
```

The JavaScript version

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Media query 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

var media_query_1 = window.matchMedia('(min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 736px) and (orientation : portrait)');
media_query_1.addListener(mediaQuery1Function);
mediaQuery1Function(media_query_1);

function mediaQuery1Function(media_query_1){
  
  if(media_query_1.matches){
  document.querySelector('#output').style.backgroundColor='red';
  } 
  
  else{
   //Nothing
  }
  
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Media query 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

var media_query_2 = window.matchMedia('(min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 736px) and (orientation : landscape)');
media_query_2.addListener(mediaQuery2Function);
mediaQuery2Function(media_query_2);

function mediaQuery2Function(media_query_2){
  
  if(media_query_2.matches){
  document.querySelector('#output').style.backgroundColor='blue';
  } 
  
  else{
   //Nothing
  }
  
}
  
});
```

```css
#output{
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<style>

</style>

<script>

</script>

<p id='output'>XXX</p>
```

Comment: `min-device-width`? Is that a typo in your CSS version?

Comment: And after fixing it, the only difference I can see from both versions is that at some point your CSS version won't apply any background because no rules will match (and that you do ignore this case in JS). For instance, if the browser's window is larger than 736px, or narrower than 320px.